# soap:ServerThese policy alternatives can not be satisfied in Jmeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter, cxf, jmeter-plugins

I get the following error in the Jmeter response

```
        ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>soap:ServerThese policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 

 {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702} AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
 {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702} InitiatorToken 
 {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702} RecipientToken
 {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702} IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
```

when I run the Jmeter request. The same works well using SOAP UI.

I see the request doesnt have the time stamp ID in an encrypted form.

Below is the request I triggerred using JMeter

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.abz.com/">
   <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
           <wsu:Timestamp>
               <wsu:Created>${CREATED}</wsu:Created>
               <wsu:Expires>${EXPIRES}</wsu:Expires>
           </wsu:Timestamp>
       </wsse:Security>
         </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:validate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <check>1007 1940 0000 0100 27</check>
      </soap:validate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Server logs:

```
Dec 07, 2017 2:57:30 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://soap.abz.com/}ServiceImplService#{http://soap.abz.com/}validate has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:167)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:198)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use the SOAP message encrypter and signer key as preprocessor in Jmeter for the SOAP request in JMeter 3.3

Any help over here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the timestamp format is wrong. If your application is indeed using WS protocol based security without any specific username and password, the below solution might work. I think you need to correct the format for your timestamp. In my case, I just used to regular HTTP sampler with the entire SOAP protocol message without using SOAP specific pre/post processors

http://abeykoon.blogspot.com/2015/03/jmeter-test-for-secured-proxy-service.html

As per the above link, you need to send the header along with username and password if your application expects that but with the correct timestamp. Code to generate one is also given in the above link. Please note that you can pass an empty value for NOnce which I did for my application. Otherwise, you need to ensure that the corresponding jboss jar file is placed under the \lib\ext directory of your JMeter installation

```
   <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-05CB7D74E166EF0AB614268666650771109">
                <wsu:Created>${#timeC#}</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>${#timeE#}</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-05CB7D74E166EF0AB614268666650771108">
                <wsse:Username>${username}</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">${password}</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">${#nonce#}</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>${#UTtimeC#}</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>   



import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.SoapSampler;
import org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.nonce.DefaultNonceGenerator; //(jbossws­core.jar)
import org.jboss.util.Base64; //this class is called inside the DefaultNonceGenerator class (jboss­common.jar)
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
 
//generating NONCE
DefaultNonceGenerator nonce_Gen = new DefaultNonceGenerator();
String nonce = nonce_Gen.generateNonce();
//generating relevant Timestamps
long ctmilli = System.currentTimeMillis(); // current time in milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat dformat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");    // timestamp format with nonce
SimpleDateFormat dformat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");  //timestamp format for usernametoken, with miliseconds
Date dtime = new Date();
dformat1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
dtime.setTime(ctmilli);  // current time
String timeCreated = dformat1.format(dtime); // timestamp created in format1
String uttimeCreated = dformat2.format(dtime); // timestamp created in format2
dtime.setTime(ctmilli+2000); // setting the timeout  for 2seconds, change the timeout as required
String timeExpire = dformat1.format(dtime);  // expiration timestamp in format1
vars.put("#timeC#",timeCreated);
vars.put("#timeE#",timeExpire);
vars.put("#nonce#",nonce);
vars.put("#UTtimeC#",uttimeCreated);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error root cause:

> Received Timestamp does not match the requirements

It appears that either `${CREATED}` or `${EXPIRES}` variables (or both) don't match server's expectations. Check their values using i.e. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination and modify the way of their generation according to what format does your server want.

Also be aware that there is [WS Security for SOAP](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity) JMeter plugin which theoretically can make your life easier. You can install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Web Service Security Plugin]